# How can I enable sys._getframe in IronPython 2.6.1?

Tags: ironpython

I'm trying to use a module that requires sys._getframe(), which, as I understand it, is not enabled by default.  I've seen a lot of material that suggests that there is a way to enable _getframe(), but I've yet to find anything that tells me how to do so.  What is the proper method for enabling this function in IronPython 2.6.1?  Does one even exist?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.  Turns out that you need to rebuild IronPython from source, with the command line options –X:Frames or –X:FullFrames.

Comment: You shouldn't have to rebuild it - those options are in the official installer.

Comment: Ha, yeah, figured that one out right when I was knee deep in the IPy source...bleh.  Thanks!