# IronPython sys._getframe not found

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

I'm currently building a program in C# which will call functions in provided python script files.
Some of these script files calls `_getframe()` in `sys`, which results in the error:

> System.MissingMemberException: 'module' object has no attribute
>   '_getframe'

(Since IronPython doesn't have `_getframe` activated by default.)

I have done quite a lot of googling and found out that you can activate it in `ipy.exe` by providing `-X:Frames` as a command line option, however this doesn't solve my problem since I'm not directly using `ipy.exe` to execute the python code.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780379/how-can-i-enable-sys-getframe-in-ironpython-2-6-1) they mention rebuilding IronPython from source with the command line options, I downloaded the source files but have no idea how to build it with those options.
Also they mention that the options are in the official installer, I have run the installer exe several times but haven't seen a glimpse of those options there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When creating the PythonEngine you can pass a dictionary of options; you just need to set the "Frames" and/or "FullFrames" keys in the dictionary to `true`:

```
var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options["Frames"] = true;
options["FullFrames"] = true;
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
```

If you don't want FullFrames, just leave it out or set it to `false`.

Answer (score 6):

A little out of the scope of the question, but meant for anyone else getting this error by invoking a Python script using the ipy.exe interpreter directly.

You can just add the argument `-X:FullFrames`. So for example invoke the script like

```
ipy.exe -X:FullFrames script.py
```