# can't use ipy -X:Frames -c "import scipy" for IronPython

Tags: scipy, ironpython

i'm trying to use Scipy in my IronPython project, 
It's said that SciPy packages make use of Cpython's stack frame inspection capabilities and by default these are not enabled in IronPython, so we have to use

> ipy -X:Frames -c "import scipy"

in command prompt, or in the Visual Studio we have to go to

> tools/options/python tools/interactive windows/

and in the interpreter options type "-X:Frames "

but in the Visual Studio i always get the error "assertion failed" (i put the link of the images in below), which forces VS to be closed

http://tinypic.com/r/287i5c1/6

Any suggestion?
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Hi @johnny,
You know, it refers to some years ago and i believe that i finally managed to work it around by myself via some tricks, 
although don't remember exactly what i did.
do you have such an issue? thus i can go deep again and find some solution for you.

Comment: I gave up on iron-python at the moment.  But if you ever do fix it, post back.  I went back to regular python.  Thanks for commenting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997832/ironpython-sys-getframe-not-found

Comment: I wish someone found an answer for this.